# Python OpenCL host program to cl program parameter passing

Tags: python, opencl

Hi I am trying OpenCL using python. I am trying to pass an array and a const variable to the cl program and simply copying the const variable to array on the cl device. This should be very simple but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#103>", line 1, in <module>
test()
File "D:/Programming/Programs_OpenCL_Python/Host_CL_Parameter_Passing.py", line 141,    in test
event = prg.test( queue, (10,1), None, a_dev, b)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl-2012.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 457, in kernel_call
self.set_args(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl-2012.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 509, in kernel_set_args
% (i+1, str(e), advice))
LogicError: when processing argument #2 (1-based): Kernel.set_arg failed: invalid     value - invalid kernel argument
```

Here's the code Code:

```
def test():
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
    a = np.empty(10, dtype = int)
    b = int(1)
    a_dev = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, a.nbytes)
    prg = cl.Program( ctx, """__kernel void test(__global int *a, const int b){
        int i = get_global_id(0);
        a[i] = b;
    }""").build()
    event = prg.test( queue, (10,1), None, a_dev, b)
    event.wait()
    cl.enqueue_copy( queue, a, a_dev)
    print a
```

Can someone tell me the problem and give me a solution? This is driving me crazy.
Thankyou

Comment: You may want to edit the title to reflect that your issue is with the scalar argument, not the array argument to your kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the integer argument to the numpy `int32` type:

```
event = prg.test( queue, (10,1), None, a_dev, np.int32(b))
```

BTW I was able to figure that out by looking at the [Mandelbrot Example](http://git.tiker.net/pyopencl.git/blob/HEAD:/examples/demo_mandelbrot.py)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. By the way, I have a 32bit python installed. Isn't default int same as numpy.int32()?

Comment: No, the python built-in `int` type not the same thing as numpy's `int32` data type.  The numpy conversion turns the Python `int` into a correct 4-byte representation that the OpenCL system is expecting.